# Design hash table with O(n) traversal, where n is number of elements

Tags: c, data-structures, hashtable

Design hash table with following operations you are given with a good hashing function..:

insert() –O(1)

find()-O(1)

delete()-O(1)

traverse()-O(n)

Comment: go ahead and do that, good luck

Comment: And your question is? Will you do my homework please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you insert elements into the hash table, you also add the elements to a linked list. When you are asked to traverse the hash table, iterate over the linked list.

Comment: And how is the delete operation O(1)?

Comment: @BryanOlivier: Doubly linked list.

Comment: To delete an element from a linked list, you first have to find the element *in the list*, which is O(n); finding its copy in the hash table doesn't help here. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @AlexShesterov: The element node is found in the hash table with O(1). The element node is also part of a doubly linked list, so it can remove itself from that. If I have to implement this for you guys, it defeats the purpose of a hint for the asker.

Comment: Ah and the elements of the list are the elements also in the hash-table (as a reference instead of value), I missed that.

Comment: @jxh But you can iterate over a hash table as well. More full the table gets more efficient is the iter.

Comment: @Armin: Question states specifically n = number of elements